# How does $a^y = x+\sqrt{x^2+1}$ imply $a^{-y} = -x+ \sqrt{x^2+1}$ and then $x=\sinh(y\ln a)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I want to understand the steps in an argument given for the following question.

> Find the inverse of the following function:
> $$f(x) = \log_a(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$$
> We find:
> $$\begin{align}
> a^y &= \phantom{-}x+\sqrt{x^2+1} \tag1 \\[4pt]
> a^{-y} &= -x+ \sqrt{x^2+1} \tag2
> \end{align}$$
> whence:
> $$x = \frac{1}{2} (a^y-a^{-y}) = \sinh(y\ln a) \tag3$$

I understand how he converts it to an exponential $(1)$, but then $(2)$ doesn’t make sense to me, as well as part $(3)$.

Comment: $(\sqrt{x°2+1}+x)(\sqrt{x^2,+1}-x)=1$

Comment: The people who downvoted should really consider whether it's helpful to immediately press the "close" button whenever a question only needs minor modifications before it is fine for the site.

Comment: You see how to get $a^y$, yes?  Just take $a$ to the power of each side of the equation above respectively.  Now, from experience they know that $a^{-y}$ can be useful to calculate as well so they do.  To do so, that is $\frac{1}{a^y}$, so let us try to look at $\frac{1}{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}$.  That's perhaps not as helpful so let's "multiply by one" in the form of $\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x-\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ at which point after simplification you get the stated result for $a^{-y}$.  You can check that the rest is correct as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right, so what you should do is to write these things out explicitly. So:
$$a^y = \sqrt{x^2+1}+x$$
$$a^{-y} = \frac{1}{a^y} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}{(x^2+1)-x^2} = \sqrt{x^2+1}-x$$
Then, notice that:
$$a^y-a^{-y} = (\sqrt{x^2+1}+x)-(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x) = 2x$$
It follows that $x = \frac{1}{2}(a^y-a^{-y})$.